# Create-react-app CSR - Applying Content Security Policy (no inline styles) when using Material UI Themes

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, content-security-policy, emotion

We have a client-side-rendering React application that makes use of the Material UI Themes libraries (which makes use of emotion library). Pseudo code looks a bit like this:

```
import { Container, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material";
import createCustomTheme, { ThemeType } from "./themes/images/theme-factory";

const theme = createCustomTheme(ThemeType.ESG);

const App: React.FC = (): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <Root />
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
```

I want to start applying a set of Content Security Policy rules including a rule to prevent inline styles from being used.

I have therefore added the following meta tag into my index.html header:

```
<meta
  http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
  content="
  script-src 'self';
  style-src 'self' ;
  img-src 'self' data: https:;">
```

This seems to apply the rules I am looking for, however when loading the application I get tonnes of errors - pretty much all saying:

> Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following
> Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self'". Either the
> 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash
> ('sha256-svexXFmNP9rIel0z5fv0U85kEaSkU3V2rqbNt8FlkR0='), or a nonce
> ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

With a pointer to the emotion-sheet.browser.esm.js file at line 132:
[image]

530 errors all pretty much the same error (3 errors are the same but for a different file).

I am aware I can put a `'unsafe-inline'` against the style-src but I do want to impose this policy.

I have read a few places about applying a hash-value to class names and then reference the hash in the meta tag - but I am not sure what this would look like or how to implement it?

If anyone has come across this issue before I would really appreciate hearing.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 2):

You basically have 3 options:

1. Add nonces. Others have raised this issue in the past https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion/issues/403, but the documentation doesn't seem to very strong and nobody seems to have figured out how to do it.
2. Add hashes. But adding 500+ hashes is not going to work well.
3. Add 'unsafe-inline'. If you can restrict certain other directives in your CSP, this might not be a bad option, see https://scotthelme.co.uk/can-you-get-pwned-with-css/